# PXE-E61 Media Test Failure Check Cable After Installing Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

Created a bootable USB containing Ubuntu Server 18.04. Configured BIOS settings to boot to USB as priority 1, installation completed (without connecting to a network...but that's a separate issue). I then booted to the single SATA HDD  in the system after removing the USB and received the above error.

Bit confused...

Checked cables, everything appears to be connected properly. This is a brand new HDD which is also formatted as part of the Ubuntu Server installation.

What else could be wrong that is worth checking?

Answer (score 0):

That error message means your computer's BIOS tried to PXE boot (boot from network), but failed because it did not detect a connected network cable. This could have happened because:

1. Your boot order lists PXE boot before HDD / disk. Ensure your HDD is listed first.
2. You have HDD above PXE, but your hard drive for some reason was undetected. Ensure your HDD is plugged in, both the SATA cable and power.
3. The boot loader wasn't installed correctly, or was corrupted in some way. Repair the bootloader, or more easily, reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Was it the E61 that led to the diagnosis? Is there a list of PXE error codes somewhere? And for 3., it's probably a lot easier/faster/better to try repairing the Ubuntu install first using the live USB and probably `bootrepair` - another install could give the same results anyway

Comment: @Xen2050 The words plainly say so: "media test failure" says it checked for media and didn't find any, so it tells you to "check cable". If you want an authoritative answer, here's a [support article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005740/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) from Intel. List of PXE error codes is just a Google search away. I'm not familiar with what repair methods Ubuntu install DVD's have, but if time isn't a concern and bootrepair isn't easy to finesse, then reinstalling is usually pretty simple and straightforward.